# Same Output - Hamming distance

Tags: python, hamming-distance

No matter what i'm trying to change, my output is always "Sensor defect detected". At first i thought it is an indetation-problem, but still it doesn't work.

```
def hamming_dist(signal_1, signal_2):
    result = []
    
    if len(signal_1['times']) != len(signal_1['data']):
        return "Empty signal on at least one of the sensors"

    if len(signal_1['data']) != len(signal_2): 
        return "Empty signal on at least one of the sensors"

    if len(signal_1) == 0 or len(signal_2) == 0:
        return "Empty signal on at least one of the sensors"


    if len(signal_1 ['data']) == len(signal_2):

        for i in range(len(signal_1 ['data'])):

            str1 = signal_1['data']
            str2 = signal_2[i]
            count_index = 0
            ham_dist = 0

            if len(str1) != len(str2):
                return "Sensor defect detected"

            while count_index < len(str1):
                if str1[count_index] != str2[count_index]:
                    ham_dist += 1
                count_index += 1
            result.append((str1, str2, ham_dist))
            i += 1

        return result
  

signal_sensor_1 = {"times": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   "data": ["00101110", "11001011", "11110000", "01000011", "11001101", "00011011"]}
signal_sensor_2 = ("00101110", "11001001", "11110011", "01111011", "11001101", "00011011")
print(hamming_dist(signal_sensor_1, signal_sensor_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            str1 = signal_1['data']
            str2 = signal_2[i]
```

One string value is an element from signal_sensor_2, e.g. in iteration 1 it is `00101110` for `str2`. `str1` is always entry `data` in your sensor_1 dictionary, e.g. always `["00101110", "11001011", "11110000", "01000011", "11001101", "00011011"]`.

You want to take element i from `signal_1['data']` by using `signal_1['data'][i]`